# How to make a div float at the same place at all time?

Tags: html, css

### What I want

- I want to make my div float, and stay there at all time -  similar to this.

[image]

### What I have

[image]

### What I've tried

### PHP

```
<div id="nav-bar">
    <ul class="inline">

        <?php 

        foreach(array_unique(array_values($continent)) as $continent_id){


            if($continent_id == 1 ) $continent_name = "Europe" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 2 ) $continent_name = "Asia" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 3 ) $continent_name = "North America" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 4 ) $continent_name = "Oceania" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 5 ) $continent_name = "South America" ;  
            else  $continent_name = "Africa" ;  

            ?>



            <li><a href="#<?php echo $continent_name ?>"><?php echo $continent_name ?></a></li>

            <?php }?>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

- Note `id="nav-bar"`

### CSS

```
#nav-bar {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100;
    left:200;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Try `position: fixed` ;)

Comment: Did you try position: fixed?

Comment: Try this [http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-sticky-scroll-plugins/](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-sticky-scroll-plugins/), it might be what you're looking for. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `position: fixed;`

`position: absolute;` puts the element at a fixed position inside its innermost *positioned* parent element. It is usually used to place an element at a fixed position inside the page.

`position: fixed;` keeps it at a fixed position inside the viewport (the browser's window).

See the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) for `position` attribute.

Comment: *position: absolute; puts the element at a fixed position inside the document* .... That statement isn't really true for the global definition.

Comment: Correct. I modified the answer.

Comment: To clarify `Position:absolute` sets the position of element relative to the closest parent with a non-static position :).

Comment: Of course. This is what I said too, I just used different words :-). The [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioned-element) specifies: _"An element is said to be **positioned** if its 'position' property has a value other than 'static'."_

Answer (score 3):

```
position:fixed;
```

add this to your div.and scroll up and down it will be float.add z-index too..

Answer (score 1):

Use these css-styles:

```
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean the same place in the browser window, you need `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add **px**(unit of measure) to **top** and **left**.
Ex:

```
top:100px;
left:200px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70xvgsvt/1